# Clojure's load-string works in the repl but not in `lein run`

Tags: clojure, leiningen

When I start a repl with `lein repl` I can run the function `greet` and it works as expected.

```
(ns var-test.core
  (:gen-class))

(declare ^:dynamic x)

(defn greet []
  (binding [x "Hello World."]
    (println (load-string "x"))))

(defn -main [& args]
  (greet))
```

But if run the code via `lein run` it fails with

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: x in this context.

What am I missing?

Is the var `x` dropped during compilation, despite being declared, since it is never used outside of the string?

Edit:

## Solution

@amalloy's comment helped me understand I need to bind `*ns*` in order load the string within the expected namespace, instead of a new, empty namespace.

This works as expected:

```
(ns var-test.core
  (:gen-class))

(declare ^:dynamic x)

(defn greet []
  (binding [x "Hello World."
            *ns* (find-ns 'var-test.core)]
    (println (load-string "x"))))

(defn -main [& args]
  (greet))
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, answering your own questions is totally fine. But please do so in a new Answer, rather than in an edit to your Question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: It's perfectly fine to add your own answer to your question on SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, I've never seen that function before!

According to the docs, `load-string` is meant to read & load forms one-at-a-time from an input string.  Observe this code, made from [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template):

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require [tupelo.string :as str]))

(dotest
  (def y "wilma")
  (throws? (eval (quote y)))
  (throws? (load-string "y"))
```

So it appears that `load-string` starts with a new, empty environment, then reads and evaluates forms one at a time in that new env.  Since your `x` is not in that new environment, it can't be found and you get an error.

Try it another way:

```
  (load-string
    (str/quotes->double

      "(def ^:dynamic x)
       (binding [x 'fred']
         (println :bb (load-string 'x'))) " ))

  ;=>  :bb fred
```

In this case, we give all the code as text to `load-string`. It reads and `eval`'s first the `def`, then the `binding` & nested `load-string` forms. Everything works as expected since the working environment contains the Var for `x`.

Some more code illustrates this:

```
(spy :cc
  (load-string
    "(def x 5)
     x "))
```

with result

```
:cc => 5
```

So the eval produces the var `x` with value `5`, then the reference to `x` causes the value `5` to be produced.

---

To my surprise, the partial `load-string` works in a fresh REPL:

```
demo.core=> (def x "fred")
#'demo.core/x
demo.core=> (load-string "x")
"fred"
```

So `load-string` must be coded to use any pre-existing
REPL environment as the base environment.  When using `lein run`, there is no REPL environment available, so `load-string` starts with an empty environment.

Comment: The difference is that `*ns*` is bound in the repl, but not when running via `-main`. `load-string` doesn't know anything about the repl, it just `eval`s forms one at a time.

Comment: Thank Alan Thompson you for your thorough answer. With @amalloy 's final remark I understood how to resolve the issue and I added a solution to my question.